# IDEA: How to import module from git?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Using `IntelliJ` idea, is it possible to import an new Module from `GIT`, similar to how `Eclipse`'s `eGit` plugin does it?

Please provide a screenshot.

Comment: In IntellIJ 2020.3 there is no VCS menu, but there *is* a git menu. So that changes step 1. for the accepted answer to: `Git` | `Clone..`

Comment: @WillemVoogd yep indeed, and it creates a new project, not a new module

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's done in two steps:

1. `VCS` | `Checkout from Version Control`, select **Git** or **GitHub**.
2. `File` | `Add Module`, **Create module from existing sources** or **Import existing module** if there is already `.iml` file in the cloned repository.

Comment: The first solution does not exist anymore, and `Git` | `Clone…` creates a new project, not a new module.

Comment: @DidierL hit "cancel" at this point, and continue with step #2

Answer (score 0):

On the filesystem there is no difference between an intellij module and a project. The only thing that makes a module is that it is part of another project. You can also open all other modules as standalone projects.

Step 1 is just to clone it from git and place it on disk, step 2 is to make it a module of the current project.